# How to publish a message to pubsub emulator using C#

Tags: c#, emulation, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I have managed to create a c# tool to push messages to google cloud pubsub. I can't seem to find anywhere how to pubslish the message to the emulator. From what I've read the following should work by passing in the endpoint to the ClientCreationSettings. But I get a bad request response back from the emulator...

```
public static async Task PublishMessage()
    {
        var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint("localhost", 8085);
        ClientCreationSettings clientSettings = new ClientCreationSettings(1, null, null, endpoint);

        string message = "hello world";

        publisherClient = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(new TopicName("project1", "topic1"), clientSettings);
        await publisherClient.PublishAsync(message);
        await publisherClient.ShutdownAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    }
```

Any insight appreciated

Comment: Do you have the actual error message that you are getting back from the emulator? Also, can you verify that you've set the environment variables when creating your topic? https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#accessing_environment_variables

Answer (score 0):

For C#, after starting the emulator with `gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID [options]` and setting the environment variable for `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST` with a handy CLI as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#env), you need to update your application code as shown in this [sample](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#accessing_environment_variables):

```
        string emulatorHostAndPort = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST");

        PublisherServiceApiClient client = new PublisherServiceApiClientBuilder
        {
            Endpoint = emulatorHostAndPort,
            ChannelCredentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure
        }.Build();
        // do things using client..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the **PubSubMessage** object instead of the string.

```
var message = new PubsubMessage(){ Data = "hello world" };
```

Your code should be like:

```
public static async Task PublishMessage()
{
    var clientSettings = new PublisherClient.ClientCreationSettings(
                null,
                PublisherServiceApiSettings.GetDefault(),
                ChannelCredentials.Insecure,
                "localhost:8085");
    
    var message = new PubsubMessage(){ Data = "hello world" };

    publisherClient = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(new TopicName("project1", "topic1"), clientSettings);
    await publisherClient.PublishAsync(message};
    await publisherClient.ShutdownAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
}
```

Source: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/